# issue with passing string to boostrap/vue component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have this:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" :small="true" :bordered="true"
:outlined="true" :head-variant="dark" :hover="false"></b-table>
```

the documentation is here:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#items-record-data-

and I'm interested in this part:
[image]

the IDE recognizes the parameter options:

[image]

yet, "dark" is not accepted:

[image]

as confirmed by the debugger:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "dark" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

what does the error mean and how can I make the 'dark' setting work?

Edit:
I found that not putting the ":" in front of head-variant works, but why is that?

Comment: I have to ask, did you try with single quotes, also did you define it in data as docs suggest? `headVariant: 'dark'`

Comment: Then in html: `:head-variant="headVariant"`

Comment: @ikiK single quotes don't change anything; I found that not putting the ':' for the bind in front of that field does work! but I'm wondering why. I'll edit the question

Comment: using `:` means its expecting a model or something computable like js, simply remove the 
 `:`. - `head-variant="dark"` its required by the rest because its true/false, else its evaluated as `String('true')` which is not boolean

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, ok, I get it! thanks! you can put this as an answer. So, from the API I can't know what needs to go with the : and what doesn't?

Comment: replying to your edit, *but why is that?* remove the `:` from any of the others, i.e `hover="false"`, then read the error it throws.

Comment: `:head-variant="varibale"` can work if you define it as variable in data,I believe. Witch is what error is suggesting.